# Image preloads in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Totally stumped on something easy... I am preloading images from an array. Everything in the code below is working well. I get a console log message after each image load. My problem - how is it possible to know when ALL images are done loading? How can I call a function when the last image loads?

Thanks for any help.

```
function function1(){

     for (i = 0; i < photoUrls.length; i++) {
         preloadPhoto(photoUrls[i]);
     }

}

function preloadPhoto(photoURL){

    $('<img class="preloadedImages"/>').attr('src', photoURL).appendTo('#front').css("width", "15%").load(function() {
        console.log('done loading image');
    });

}
```

Comment: Put another console.log after the for loop.

Comment: @Moniecorleone: That won't help, as this is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have one global variable which will keep record of photos loaded till now.

```
var totalPhotosloaded = 0;


function function1(){

     for (i = 0; i < photoUrls.length; i++) {
         preloadPhoto(photoUrls[i]);
     }

}

function preloadPhoto(photoURL){

    $('<img class="preloadedImages"/>').attr('src', photoURL).appendTo('#front').css("width", "15%").load(function() {
        console.log('done loading image');
        totalPhotosloaded++;
if(totalPhotosloaded == photoUrls.length){
//call your function here.
   }
  });       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count.

```
var preloadedCount = 0;

// Then further down inside your `.load` function

console.log('done loading image');
preloadedCount++;

if(preloadedCount == photoUrls.length){
  // All images have been preloaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a counter and checking it as each photo loads is one way to go.

check out this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rJsGgpRlnTyUf246aX6c?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do this with a somewhat different technique.  I would use promises to handle both the individual updates and the group one:

```
function preloadAllPhotos(photoUrls, afterEach){
    var promises = [], promise, afterEach = afterEach || $.noop;
    for (var i = 0; i < photoUrls.length; i++) {
        promise = preloadPhoto(photoUrls[i])
        promises.push(promise);
        promise.then(afterEach);
    }
    return $.when.apply(null, promises);
}

function preloadPhoto(photoUrl){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('<img class="preloadedImages"/>').attr('src', photoUrl)
            .appendTo('#front').css("width", "15%").load(function() {
        defer.resolve(photoUrl);
    });
    return defer.promise();
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
var logPhoto = function(photoUrl) {
    console.log('done loading image ' + photoUrl);
};

var logComplete = function() {
    // `arguments` contains all the photo urls
    console.log("done loading all photos")
};

preloadAllPhotos(photoUrls, logPhoto).then(logComplete);
```

You can see this **[in action on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/9hsGs/)**.

This adds some additional flexibility.  In fact, I would probably go further and separate out the DOM appending from this loading code, but that's for a different thread.